# Anaconda update on Linux throws error “TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'msg'”. How to get Anaconda updated?

Tags: updates, anaconda

Running an update for Anaconda with:

```
root@admin:/home/user/Downloads# sh Anaconda3-2023.09-0-Linux-x86_64.sh -u
```

Leads to the error:

```shell
Anaconda3 will now be installed into this location:
/home/user/anaconda3

  - Press ENTER to confirm the location
  - Press CTRL-C to abort the installation
  - Or specify a different location below

[/home/user/anaconda3] >>> 
PREFIX=/home/user/anaconda3
Unpacking payload ...
Extracting : pytest-6.2.3-py38h06a4308_2.conda:  18%|███████████████████████████                                                                                                                            | 148/825 [01:43<09:21,  1.21it/s]Exception in thread Thread-2:
concurrent.futures.process._RemoteTraceback:                                                                                                                                                                                                  
'''
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "concurrent/futures/process.py", line 387, in wait_result_broken_or_wakeup
  File "multiprocessing/connection.py", line 256, in recv
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'msg'
'''

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "entry_point.py", line 69, in <module>
  File "concurrent/futures/process.py", line 562, in _chain_from_iterable_of_lists
  File "concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 609, in result_iterator
  File "concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 446, in result
  File "concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 391, in __get_result
concurrent.futures.process.BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.
[23797] Failed to execute script 'entry_point' due to unhandled exception!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "threading.py", line 980, in _bootstrap_inner
  File "concurrent/futures/process.py", line 323, in run
  File "concurrent/futures/process.py", line 458, in terminate_broken
  File "concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 549, in set_exception
concurrent.futures._base.InvalidStateError: CANCELLED: <Future at 0x7f669d2c88b0 state=cancelled>
^C
```

Which ends up like this after cancelling with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>:

```shell
Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
Process ForkProcess-1:
Process ForkProcess-2:
Process ForkProcess-4:
Process ForkProcess-3:
  File "multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 27, in poll
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
  File "multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
  File "concurrent/futures/process.py", line 240, in _process_worker
  File "multiprocessing/queues.py", line 102, in get
  File "multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 95, in __enter__
KeyboardInterrupt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
  File "multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
  File "concurrent/futures/process.py", line 240, in _process_worker
  File "multiprocessing/queues.py", line 102, in get
  File "multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 95, in __enter__
KeyboardInterrupt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
  File "multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
  File "concurrent/futures/process.py", line 240, in _process_worker
  File "multiprocessing/queues.py", line 102, in get
  File "multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 95, in __enter__
KeyboardInterrupt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
  File "multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
  File "concurrent/futures/process.py", line 240, in _process_worker
  File "multiprocessing/queues.py", line 103, in get
  File "multiprocessing/connection.py", line 221, in recv_bytes
  File "multiprocessing/connection.py", line 419, in _recv_bytes
  File "multiprocessing/connection.py", line 384, in _recv
KeyboardInterrupt
KeyboardInterrupt
```

What to do to get the update done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what happened there, but running the update command again was enough:

```shell
Do you accept the license terms? [yes|no]
[no] >>> yes    

Anaconda3 will now be installed into this location:
/root/anaconda3

  - Press ENTER to confirm the location
  - Press CTRL-C to abort the installation
  - Or specify a different location below

[/root/anaconda3] >>> 
PREFIX=/root/anaconda3
Unpacking payload ...
Extracting : typing-extensions-4.7.1-py311h06a4308_0.conda:  79%|▊| 409/517 [06:
                                                                                
Installing base environment...


Downloading and Extracting Packages


Downloading and Extracting Packages

Preparing transaction: done
Executing transaction: \ 

    Installed package of scikit-learn can be accelerated using scikit-learn-intelex.
    More details are available here: https://intel.github.io/scikit-learn-intelex

    For example:

        $ conda install scikit-learn-intelex
        $ python -m sklearnex my_application.py

    

done
installation finished.
```